# What is the difference between mount -t nfs3 and mount -t nfs -o nfsvers=3?

Tags: nfs, nfs4, rpc

While mounting a share I had issues with `idmapping`. Mounting with

```
sudo mount -t nfs 192.168.0.23:/myshare ./myshare -o nolock
```

and listing its contents yielded this (note the `nobody` and `4294967294`):

```
-rwx------ 1 nobody 4294967294   48 Sep 27  1998 somefile
```

When I actually expected this:

```
-rwx------ 1 1023 1023   48 Sep 27  1998 somefile
```

I tried using NFSv3 by specifying `-t nfs3` without luck:

```
sudo mount -t nfs3 192.168.0.23:/myshare ./myshare -o nolock,nfsvers=3
```

After a bit of research, the `nfsvers=3` option did the trick

```
sudo mount -t nfs 192.168.0.23:/myshare ./myshare -o nolock,nfsvers=3
ls -la myshare

...
-rwx------ 1 1023 1023   48 Sep 27  1998 somefile
```

My question is: what's the difference between the `nfsvers=3` option and `-t nfs3`? Shouldn't they be the same thing?

Comment: For clarity, which os is this that has a "nfs3" mount type (I suppose, from a different perspective, which has a mount.nfs3 program)? I guess the question is related to some difference in behavior between the mount.nfs and mount.nfs3 programs in your environment that goes beyond just the nfs version (which you can pass to mount.nfs).

Answer (score 3):

@håkan-lindqvist is onto the answer. I don't have a `mount.nfs3` but I have a `mount.nfs4` and it is just a symlink to `mount.nfs`. I looked at the source for `mount.nfs` and it doesn't do anything special based on the basename of `argv[0]` (except for unmounting). Thus `mount -t nfs4` would not specify the version at all. I suspect the same for `-t nfs3`.

So, to answer your questions: they are not the same thing and `-t nfs3` doesn't specify the nfs version.

Comment: Interesting... makes me wonder why would `-t nfs3` and `-t nfs4` even exist. Perhaps some legacy backwards compatibility?